# How to listen to Ip/port continously for data using TCP/IP protocol?

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcp

I'm trying to develop a program(windows service, basically) to continuously listen to an IP and PORT on which a device will be sending data at 30 sec interval using telnet.

Now, I have googled a lot and as I understand TCPClient or TCPListener can be used to receive data from telnet. I have gone through a few solution on internet but most of them are once write and read solution but I need to listen to that IP continuously. I don't have to send anything just listen for the data and save that in SQL SERVER DB(I have done with this code). Following is the client code that I have tried:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        msg("Client Started");
        clientSocket.Connect(IPAdd, 23);
        label1.Text = "Client Socket Program - Server Connected ...";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

        StreamReader objstream = new StreamReader(path, UnicodeEncoding.Unicode);
        //textBox1.Text = objstream.ReadLine();

        byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objstream.ReadToEnd() + "$");
        serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
        serverStream.Flush();

        byte[] inStream = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
        serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
        string returndata = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
        msg(returndata);
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox2.Focus();

        string path = @"D:\TELNETResponse.txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path);
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
            tw.WriteLine(returndata);
            tw.Close();
        }
        else if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {
                tw.WriteLine(returndata);
                tw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: As i said a device is posting data to a specific IP/PORT every  30 seconds and I have to listen to that port, get that data.

Comment: That is not a problem, that is a requirement.  What is wrong with the code you show?  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Usually, you'd start a thread that listens (indefinitely if not explicitly shut down) for incoming connection requests. If that happens, you'd spawn a thread to handle the connection. See https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5733/A-TCP-IP-Server-written-in-C

Comment: You seem to connect to the device via telnet, though. If so, just spawn a listening thread on the TCPClient after you connected.

Comment: BTW: You shouldn't be doing Network I/O on the GUI thread. This can lead to GUI freezes.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - The problem is that it listens to data sent only once and then closes but i want to listen continuously....

Answer (score 0):

So what you are going to want to do is setup a while loop if you want to listen continuously and that's the only operation this application does. Your code should look like something below:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string data;
    NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(serverStream, Encoding.Default);
    string path = @"D:\TELNETResponse.txt";
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Create(path);
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
        tw.WriteLine(returndata);
        tw.Close();
    }
    while ((data = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
        {
            tw.WriteLine(returndata);
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The `streamReader` will only become `NULL` if the connection drops, at which point you would want to setup some code to reconnect.

Comment: That is going to block the main UI thread.  Either need async io or separate thread

Comment: And based upon the question asked, I figure that's OK in this instance. It should be it's own thread, but then again this entire thing seems like it should be a console application to begin with.